# Logging for C program

Tags: c, linux, logging

I need some clever logging library for a daemon-like `C` (not `C++`) program on Linux. It needs to be open-source. It should support logging to files, maybe sockets etc.

Or at least some good tips or tricks or best practices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158457/logging-in-linux)

Comment: And take note of http://stackoverflow.com/q/158749/2509 concerning networkability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [syslog](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/syslog.3.html)() . This decouples your in program logging from how the logs are handled. [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) is used on most Linux distributions nowadays, and allows great flexibility on how the logs are processed.

Answer (score 1):

the following is something that you could do .

I am assuming your C application runs as a deamon and hence you cannot frintf the logging messages . syslog() is certainly an option for routing you messages . syslog() is very option the location where deamons write their messages and the adminstrators parse the contents of the syslog file to reach meaningful conclusions . Also syslog has a particual logging format . However i wish the propose that you write your own logging scheme . It is often what is desireable in enterprise software and not logging into syslog . Do this

1 . in you main configuration file define a logging macro

```
 #define LOG_ERR log_err
```

having a definition like 
     log_err(int errno,char *logger , char *text)
the api should log details to a log file .

1. any c file which includes the main configuration file can just use the macro

   LOG_ERR(errno,"handle_submission()","Submission of job failed ")

You should also include time stamps in the logger file .