# How to configure syslog so that an applications log goes to a specific file

Tags: c++, linux, syslog, rsyslog

I have an application `myapp` which should send log files *only* to `/var/log/myapp.log`. `myapp` is written in C++. The following sample code, sends the logs to /var/log/syslog only. My os is Linux - Ubuntu 12.04 - to be specific. I also found that my machine has rsyslog than syslog installed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>

int main(void) {
    openlog("myapp", LOG_PID|LOG_CONS, LOG_USER);
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "abc 10");
    closelog();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the syslog(3) manpage, the first parameter for openlog() sets a prefix for log messages, not a filename.
You can use a facility like LOG_LOCAL0 to flag your output and then [configure syslogd using /etc/syslog.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/make-a-log-file) to send those logs to the file of your desire.

Comment: How to configure syslog.conf so that the log messages from my application go to a specific file ? Writing onto a simple file is not a good solution - read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158457/logging-in-linux and the answer given by http://stackoverflow.com/users/7740/richard

Comment: @suresh You can directly give the link to an answer by copying the link location from the 'share' link after each answer. Like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/158493/598175

Answer (score 2):

If your Ubuntu is working with [rsyslog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd), you need to find the configuration file  /etc/rsyslog.conf and modify it.

```
$ echo "if \$programname == 'myapp' then /var/log/myapp.log \n& ~" >> /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Then you restart the utility:

```
$ sudo service rsyslog restart
```

And run your programm:

```
$ ./myapp
```

Check your log:

```
$ cat /var/log/myapp.log 
Apr  8 14:01:51 myusername myapp[21508]: abc 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

1. Add to the config **/etc/rsyslog.conf**

> :programname,contains,"myapp" /var/log/myapp.log

2. `service rsyslog restart`