# keeping syslog into a specific file

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, logging, syslog

I use the following code below ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158457/logging-in-linux)) to keep the log files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>

int main(void) {

 openlog("slog", LOG_PID|LOG_CONS, LOG_USER);
 syslog(LOG_INFO, "A different kind of Hello world ... ");
 closelog();

 return 0;
}
```

I run the program on ubuntu and it keeps the logs on `/var/log/syslog`, how can I set the logs to be kept on e.g. `/var/log/mylog`?

Comment: Check this file: `/etc/syslog.conf`

Comment: You can set it in the [syslog configuration file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf).

Comment: I read that file before posting the question here, forgive me that I could not really understand what exactly I need to do there. I would appreciate if you could explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During openlog, use a special facility, so that you can modify your syslog.conf file to direct such logs to any log file you specified.

Don't forget to remove such facility from the default syslog - by default all logs goes to syslog.

Comment: Could you tell me what facility argument do I need to pass into openlog and how do I need to specify the name of the file that logs needs to be written? I would appreciate if you could explain it by modifying the code above

Comment: You may use LOG_LOCAL0 or other facilities instead of LOG_USER. I can't remember all, but you should be able to find those if you check the header file.